# cannot convert from 'initializer list' to template<int>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initialization, initializer-list

That's my class:

I'm overloading the operator&& to determine whether an interval has anything in common with a given interval and i'm trying to make an exception for when they dont have anything in common so it will return an interval with two of the same values,which will have to print "EMPTY" within the constructor,but it won't compile due to something with the initializer list.
my class: (removed any irrelveant functions)

```
class Interval
{
public:
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &output, const Interval<T> & it) {
        if (&it)
            it.print();
        return output;
    }
    friend istream & operator>>(istream &input, Interval<T> & it) {
        it.enter();
        return input;
    }
    Interval();
    Interval(const T &, const T &);
    Interval<T> operator&&(Interval<T> &it);
    Interval<T> operator||(Interval<T> &it);
    ~Interval();
private:
    T a;
    T b;
    int flag;
};
```

the function of the overloading &&:

```
template <class T>
Interval<T> Interval<T>::operator&&(Interval<T> &i1) {
    if (b < i1.a)
        return Interval<T>(i1, i1);
    else if (b == i1.a) 
        return Interval<T>(i1, i1);
    else if (a > i1.b) 
        return Interval<T>(i1, i1);
    else if (a == i1.b) 
        return Interval<T>(i1, i1);
    else {
        if (a<i1.a){
            if (b < i1.b)
                return Interval<T>(i1.a, b);
            else return Interval<T>(i1.a, i1.b);
        }
        if (i1.a < a) {
            if (i1.b < b)
                return Interval<T>(a, i1.b);
            else return Interval<T>(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

my constructor:

```
Interval<T>::Interval(const T &t1, const T &t2) {
    a = t1;
    b = t2;
    if (t1 == t2) {
        cout << "EMPTY";
    }
    flag = 0;
}
```

and here are the warnings that i get due to that problem.

```
Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Interval<int>'
```

what is wrong with what i did?

Comment: Where the error applies?

Comment: `if (&it)` unless you implement unary `operator &`, condition would always be true.

Comment: @Jarod42 how would u fix the issue with the &it? because i've learned by now that i can't compare Referance to NULL as the compiler will always take it as true,but how can i fix that ? (check whether an object has anything)

Comment: @Apocaly I added an explanation to my answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list'
>                  to 'Interval<int>'
>
> no matching constructor for initialization of 'Interval<int>'
>        return Interval<T>(i1, i1);
> ```

You do not have a constructor taking two `Interval<T>`'s and `i1` *is* an `Interval<T>`. You'll have to construct it using two `T`'s (`int`:s in this case).

Suggestion: `&&` is usually used for boolean operations where the result is either `true` or `false`. If you want to return `a ∩ b` (the intersection), I think `T T::operator&(const T2 &b) const;` would be more fitting. Note the `const`:s! You are not supposed to change any of the values, but return a newly constructed `Interval<T>`.

Also, the `if(&it)` is not necessary. `it` is a `const Interval<T>&` (a reference) - and references must always reference something, hence, `&it` can't return `nullptr`. If `it` would have been a `const Interval<T>*` (a pointer) on the other hand, it could have been `nullptr` and then the check would have made sense. References are nice that way!

Another note: You don't have to use the `<T>` after `Interval` inside your class definition. `Interval` means `Interval<T>` by default. Only if you'd like to mix it with another `Interval` type would you need to supply the type for it. Like in:

```
template<typename T>
class Interval {
    template<typename U>
    void something(Interval& a, Interval<U>& b) {
        // a is an Interval<T>&
        // b is an Interval<U>&
    }
};
```

You also don't need to make the streaming operators `friend`s since they don't access the `private` members directly. You have your `print()` and `enter()` member functions for that.

Here are more details and suggestions with comments in the code:

```
#include <algorithm>  // std::min, std::max
#include <iostream>

// half-open interval:  [a, b)
template<typename T>
class Interval
{
public:
    // default constructs an empty interval
    Interval() : 
        Interval({}, {})  // delegating to the below constructor
    {}

    Interval(const T& t1, const T& t2) : // <- use the member initializer list
        a{t1},
        b{t2},
        flag{0}
    {
        if(b < a) b = a; // illegal, make it empty
        if(a == b) std::cout << "EMPTY\n";
    }

    // itersection
    Interval operator&(const Interval& it) const {
        // Construct the Interval<T> using copy-list-initialization.
        // A return statement with braced-init-list used as the return expression
        // and list-initialization initializes the returned object.

        return  {
                    std::max(a, it.a), // get the greatest lower bound
                    std::min(b, it.b)  // get the smallest upper bound
                };
    }

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const {        
        return os << '[' << a << ',' << b << ')';
    }

    std::istream& enter(std::istream& is) {        
        return is >> a >> b;
    }

private:
    T a;
    T b;
    int flag;
};

// streaming operators do not need to be friends since they use public member functions
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Interval<T>& it) {
    return it.print(output);
}

template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Interval<T>& it) {
    return it.enter(input);
}

int main() {
    Interval<int> x(0, 10);
    Interval<int> y(5, 15);

    Interval<int> u; // using the new default constructor
    u = x & y;
    std::cout << u << '\n'; // [5,10)

    std::cout << (Interval<int>(0,20) & Interval<int>(5,15)) << '\n'; // [5,15)
    std::cout << (Interval<int>(0,10) & Interval<int>(10,20)) << '\n'; // EMPTY [10,10)
    std::cout << (Interval<int>(100,200) & Interval<int>(0,100)) << '\n'; // EMPTY [100,100)
}
```

Comment: That's so helpful!! i've learned alot from your comment as i've noticed a couple of things that i did wrong.
thank you so much for your comment!!!

Comment: Thanks for adding explanation about the nullptr and for the template, that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of errors in your code.

I'm guessing you have a `template <typename T>` above your class, or the whole code is wrong

The most important one is inside your operator `&&`

You have declared only one constructor that takes 2 arguments, both being `const T&`.
Yet inside your member function you mix constructor calls with either

```cpp
const T&, const T&
const Interval<T>&, const Interval<T>&
const T&, const Interval<T>&
const Interval<T>&, const T&
```

Some of those calls will fail as you have only provided the following constructors.

```cpp
Interval();
Interval(const T &, const T &);
// and copy/move constructors, if possible
```

There's also an issue with your stream operators, you take a stream, but you ignore it, you take your argument by a const reference, yet you check if it's not `nullptr`, references must not be "made" from a `nullptr`, it's undefied behavior.

As a side note, try your code with different compilers, clang gives the following warning, which is much more readable.

```
<source>:31:16: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Interval<int>'
        return Interval<T>(i1, i1);
               ^           ~~~~~~

<source>:65:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'Interval<int>::operator&&' requested here
    x && y;
```

Comment: I was acting wrong with the template concept !! thank to your comment i've noticed that I was working completly wrong with all the constructors and even with using <class T> instead of <typename T>,and as for the nullptr issue with the ostream and istream functions,how would you do that differently to check whether and object has something at all without using NULL? (as its illegal behavior)

Comment: There is no difference between <class T> and <typename T>, whichever you use is a code style issue. As for the NULL check, you just don't have to do that, `ostream &output` is not a pointer, it's a reference, it can **_never_** be NULL. If you somehow manage to make a NULL reference, by let's say, dereferencing a pointer, which can be NULL, you invoke undefined behavior, and whatever happens in your program from that point depends on the compiler, it can work, it can crash, it can make demons fly out of your nose.